# adb.exe not giving any results

Tags: android, windows, command-line, adb

I've recently purchases my first Android device - a Nexus 5 - and I'd like to play around with it. Since it's a pure Android phone I'd thought testing the most basic program on it would be a breeze, but I just can't get it to work on my Windows 7 laptop.

Step 1 is getting the driver to work. This works I think, since in the Device Manager displays an 'Android Device', with subtext 'Android Composite ADB Interface'.

I also have USB debugging enabled on my device.

Now, to test whether my device is connected properly, I understood I need to run `adb.exe` under `C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools`. So in my cmd I cd to the location and run this command, a window (presumably adb.exe) pops up and does some things, dissapears again and... nothing else happens. I'm not used to using the cmd-line, so perhaps I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not getting any results. Also `adb.exe` seems to keep running on my computer.

[image]

Any ideas?

**Edit** I had already tried running `adb devices` as well. This gave the same result. However, I noticed an Avast!-interface around the box of adb.exe. Disabeling my antivirus made a device show up. Thanks!

Comment: if your device is listed under the Device Manager, then you are good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Just replace `adb.exe` by `adb devices` in the last command you typed (in your screenshot).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should probably just try `adb devices` in the prompt and see if you get a list of attached devices